# Visual Studio template for generating LINQ to SQL classes?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2013

I notice that my Windows Phone 8 project doesn't have the LINQ to SQL Classes template, used to generate classes mapped to relational objects and a DataContext. 
I've read some topics in the Windows Phone Dev Center on how to use LINQ to SQL and they make the classes manually, like in this one: [How to create a local database app with MVVM for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh286405%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

[This topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202872%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) talks about the limitations of the Windows Phone 8 version of LINQ to SQL, but doesn't mention anything about this template. 
I wonder why Microsoft took it out?

Is there any other template in Visual Studio used for the same purpose?

Comment: I don't know much about the template, but if you're going to create the mapping manually you could have a look at [SqlMetal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I have used SQLite and have been very happy with it. Here is a link to a blogpost on Nokia's website detailing how to add it. (it will require you to create classes to resemble the data, but you probably want to do that anyway).

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone

It's actually pretty easy once you wire the few pieces together.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/). It works really well - you can create tables and relations graphically, and it will create the classes and DataContext for you.